# How do I center an inline-block/floated header with no extra markup?

Tags: html, css

I have a variable width header that **must** have a background color that is as wide as the text (no wider). The only way I can think of doing this (with no extra markup) is to set the display to inline-block or float it to the left. The problem then though is that I cannot center the header (another requirement).

The closest I have got so far is by setting `position: relative;` on a floated header, pushing it across 50% from the left and then pulling it back 25% with negative margin, however this does not consistently center the header. It must remain in the flow of the document so `position: absolute;` is another no-go.

If you are aware of a way to do this using CSS **only** with **no extra markup** please let me know (pseudo-elements are fine, I'm not hassled about IE7 support)!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Solved using display: table; on the heading (with margin: 0 auto;).

Answer (score 7):

you can give `text-align:center;` to the `body` as a global arrtibute & give `display:inline-block` to your `header` div. So,it's center your `dynamic width` in `center` like this :

CSS:

```
body{margin:0; padding:0;text-align:center}
p{text-align:left;}
.header{background:red;display:inline-block;}
```

Check this example http://jsfiddle.net/vpcXS/

Comment: As said in the comment on the first answer, this solution is not ideal at all, although it may be the only solution. Thanks anyway.

Comment: i didn't know is a ideal solution but in not a bad solution. It's a type of reset.

Comment: @joshua I think this solution is actually better then yours.

Comment: @joshua because `display: table` is not supported on low IEs, which you may or may not care.

Answer (score -1):

replace the p tag with center as my markup is

```
<div id="header">
    <center>hello</center>
</div>
```

and it's CSS is

```
body{
    width:100%;
}
#header{
    text-align:center;
}
#header center{
    display:inline-block;
    background:red;
}
```

Comment: you can adjust the height of center equal to the height of your header so it will looks like header.

Comment: As mentioned in the post, A solution with no extra markup is required.