# Centering in-line element like block level elements

Tags: html, css

I want to know if there is a way to put in-line elements in the center just like block level elements. I know I can make a `header` in the center using this method:

```
header {
    text-align: center;
}
```

But when I put a `ul` inside as a child, the `ul` elements are not centered:

```
<style>
header {
    text-align: center;
}
header ul {
    list-style: none;
    position: center;
    text-align: center;
}
</style>
<header>
<ul class="centerd">
    <li><a href="facebook.com">Facebook</a></li>
    <li><a href="google.com">Google</a></li>
    <li><a href="youtube.com">Youtube</a></li>
</ul>
</header>
```

As you can see, I have used text-align for both `header` and `ul` but still the list elements are on the left of the screen and not center.
Can someone help please?

Comment: `position: center;`is not a valid value for that property.

Comment: @FabrizioCalderan I removed that and still the same.

Comment: And in case you didn't notice, the `<header>` is inside the `<style>` tag

Comment: @FabrizioCalderan Fixed it, but that is not the problem

Comment: Header and UL are both block-level elements, text-align will only impact the text or inline elements inside them.

Comment: check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7279294/how-do-i-center-an-inline-block-floated-header-with-no-extra-markup